# What is redirect-url field in linkedin application regiration

Tags: linkedin-api

I am new to linkedin app development. i just want to know what i need to give in the redirect-url field.
I am getting an error Invalid redirect URI. Can any one help me out

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally redirect uri is used for getting server response values...!

(i.e) I'm passing `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI`

This `YOUR_REDIRECT_URI` could be anything... mine was `example.com/callback` And in return from above i can get authorization code

```
example.com/callaback/?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&state=STATE
```

So finally in your code you can get this authorization code.

For more information please see this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#oauth2-redirect-uri)

Comment: can you please give code

Comment: @KingslyDavid You didn't mention what language you are using ?

Comment: I am using php 5.0.3

Comment: sorry i don't have any experience with php. But if you want i can provide you the link ...

Comment: Raja i followed the steps mentioned in the link you have sent me. But still i am facing the error. Can you please share me a proper redirect-url so that i will try with that

Comment: @KingslyDavid i found this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/oauth-20-redirect-url-faq-invalid-redirecturi-error) it may help you .. let me know ...